# Grunt JS / Yeoman Generator with Sass, Compass, Susy

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, gruntjs, bower

New to Grunt JS. Trying to add Compass/Susy to a project that I created with Grunt/Yeoman. Not 100% sure how the difffernece but here is what i think and the overall synopsis of my problem:

- Bower - strictly a package manager (lets me download and include the latest version of XYZ
- Yeoman - a scaffolding. Quickly creates the barebones of a XYZ project
- Grunt JS - compiles the project as I'm working on it.

If those are correct, great. I'm still running an issue when trying to include Compass into my project. All articles, blogposts or docs I've found seem to be a bit old (mid 2013) so not sure if documentation changed or anything. I've even referred to the `grunt-contrib-compass` docs but can't seem to figure out whats going on.

When I run the yeoman webapp generator I *only* include Modernizr from the three initial options (Bootstrap, Sass, Modernizr). I've tried including Compass when I've already included Sass from the generator and it always results in errors.

I've downloaded and included `grunt-contrib-compass` in the dev of my project, its included in my package.json file. From there, I've added the Compass Grunt options into my `gruntfile.js` and I've, luckily, had no error thus far. But nothing works. The file isn't being watched. I have no clue if Compass has been added corretly or at all.

Any Help?

Below are my `package.json`, `gruntfile.js`, and `bower.json`.

More than happy to provide anything else.

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "testapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "~0.7.2",
    "grunt-bower-install": "~1.4.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-mocha": "~0.4.10",
    "grunt-modernizr": "~0.5.2",
    "grunt-newer": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-rev": "~0.1.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "~2.1.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "~0.1.5",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.4.0",
    "time-grunt": "~0.3.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  }
```

}

## Gruntfile.js

```
// Generated on 2014-06-12 using generator-webapp 0.4.9
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Load grunt tasks automatically
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    // Configurable paths
    var config = {
        app: 'app',
        dist: 'dist'
    };

    // Define the configuration for all the tasks
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Project settings
        config: config,

        // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
        watch: {
            bower: {
                files: ['bower.json'],
                tasks: ['bowerInstall']
            },
            js: {
                files: ['<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['jshint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            jstest: {
                files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['test:watch']
            },
            gruntfile: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js']
            },
            styles: {
                files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
                tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            sass: {
                files: ['**/*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['compass:dist']
            },
            css: {
                    files: ['<%= config.app %>/_sass/*.scss'],
                    tasks: ['compass:dist']
                  },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                },
                files: [
                    '<%= config.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                    '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= config.app %>/images/{,*/}*'
                ]
            }
        },

        // The actual grunt server settings
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                open: true,
                livereload: 35729,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function(connect) {
                        return [
                            connect.static('.tmp'),
                            connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')),
                            connect.static(config.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    open: false,
                    port: 9001,
                    middleware: function(connect) {
                        return [
                            connect.static('.tmp'),
                            connect.static('test'),
                            connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')),
                            connect.static(config.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    base: '<%= config.dist %>',
                    livereload: false
                }
            }
        },

        // Empties folders to start fresh
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/*',
                        '!<%= config.dist %>/.git*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },

        // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
            },
            all: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                '<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '!<%= config.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
                'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        },

        // Mocha testing framework configuration options
        mocha: {
            all: {
                options: {
                    run: true,
                    urls: ['http://<%= connect.test.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.test.options.port %>/index.html']
                }
            }
        },

        // Add vendor prefixed styles
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 1 version']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css',
                    dest: '.tmp/styles/'
                }]
            }
        },


        // compass
        compass: {
          dist: {
            options: {
              require: 'susy',
              sassDir: '_sass',
              cssDir: 'styles',
              config: 'config.rb'
            }
          }
        },




        // Automatically inject Bower components into the HTML file
        bowerInstall: {
            app: {
                src: ['<%= config.app %>/index.html'],
                exclude: ['bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js']
            }
        },

        // Renames files for browser caching purposes
        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.*',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/*.{ico,png}'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
        // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
        // additional tasks can operate on them
        useminPrepare: {
            options: {
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
            },
            html: '<%= config.app %>/index.html'
        },

        // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
        usemin: {
            options: {
                assetsDirs: ['<%= config.dist %>', '<%= config.dist %>/images']
            },
            html: ['<%= config.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
        },

        // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },

        svgmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },

        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                    removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                    removeOptionalTags: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    useShortDoctype: true
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.dist %>',
                    src: '{,*/}*.html',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
                }]
            }
        },

        // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
        // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
        // to use the Usemin blocks.
        // cssmin: {
        //     dist: {
        //         files: {
        //             '<%= config.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
        //                 '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
        //                 '<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
        //             ]
        //         }
        //     }
        // },
        // uglify: {
        //     dist: {
        //         files: {
        //             '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
        //                 '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
        //             ]
        //         }
        //     }
        // },
        // concat: {
        //     dist: {}
        // },

        // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        'images/{,*/}*.webp',
                        '{,*/}*.html',
                        'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            styles: {
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css'
            }
        },

        // Generates a custom Modernizr build that includes only the tests you
        // reference in your app
        modernizr: {
            dist: {
                devFile: 'bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
                outputFile: '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/vendor/modernizr.js',
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        '!<%= config.dist %>/scripts/vendor/*'
                    ]
                },
                uglify: true
            }
        },

        // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up build process
        concurrent: {
            server: [
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            test: [
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            dist: [
                'copy:styles',
                'imagemin',
                'svgmin'
            ]
        }
    });

    // load plugins 
    // load plugins
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');


    grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'concurrent:server',
            'autoprefixer',
            'connect:livereload',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
        grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
        grunt.task.run([target ? ('serve:' + target) : 'serve']);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', function (target) {
        if (target !== 'watch') {
            grunt.task.run([
                'clean:server',
                'concurrent:test',
                'autoprefixer'
            ]);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'connect:test',
            'mocha'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        'concat',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'copy:dist',
        'modernizr',
        'rev',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'newer:jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);
};
```

## bower.json

```
{
  "name": "testapp",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "modernizr": "~2.6.2",
    "jquery": "~1.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a half-answer, and something I'm working one myself but haven't had the time to work through completely.  You can use the Angular WebApp generator which has compass built in and then go ahead and strip out much of the angular if you want to.

In terms of getting compass up and running that type of projects it's somewhat straightforward, but not well documented.  [I wrote about it here](https://medium.com/pixels-process/setting-up-grunt-compass-with-compass-plugin-version-control-bfc1d2dee07).

The Compass processing should be all setup for you in Grunt.js as well as Compass contrib in your package.json file. It'll look like this, I've added the options for compass requirements and Bundler:

```
 compass: {
      options: {

        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
        generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
        importPath: './bower_components',
        httpImagesPath: '/images',
        httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
        httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
        relativeAssets: false,
        assetCacheBuster: false,
        raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n',
        bundleExec: 'true',
        require: ['susy','breakpoint']
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
        }
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          debugInfo: true
        }
      }
    }
```

Any file you want to change and have the project change in need to be in the watch function part of the file. Mine looks like this:

```
    watch: {
     /// other things being watched
     compass: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/sass/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
          },
    }
```

I'm basically watching all files inside styles with scss and sass endings.  I also setup a sass directory I added to watch.

Hope this helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

I also used the [yeoman/generator-webapp](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp) and I wanted also to use compass.

I followed the instruction provided on the same page under the Docs heading [(We have recipes for integrating other popular technologies like Compass.](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/blob/master/docs/recipes/compass.md))

If you already have the compass gem installed and and grunt-contrib-compass via npm, then you just go ahead replace the sass options with compass options and the update your watch and concurrent tasks in your grunt.js file.

Furthermore I also added for my own need susy, breakpoint and html5 and normalize gems and then updated my grunt.js file with the following: `require: ['susy','breakpoint','compass-h5bp']` Note, don't forget to add a comma to that snippet if this is not your last line in your compass option.